# Hazelcast Adding Index for Map with Objects of different classes implementing same interface

Tags: java, indexing, interface, hazelcast

I have a map which contains objects of 4 different classes all of which implements the same interface. I want indexing to be on the result of a method in the interface (which returns a specific attribute for each of the 4 classes). The attribute name might be arrived in a nested manner in the method due to which I can't directly use the attribute name in the index. How to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

@jeffy-jahfar, If the method you'll call has no arguments, simply (re)name it as `getXXX` and define `XXX` as index name. Hazelcast first tries to call the getter method, if not then access the field directly. This way you can index the result of this method call.